# Symfony2 Content Encoding Error in production error pages

Tags: php, apache, encoding, symfony, http-headers

I've got this error only on a specific host, and only with symfony2 application. This error appears on all s2 generated error pages - 404, 500, etc. 
I'm using symfony2 on two other production servers (and 3 local ones) and this problem never occurred there. Also I've been hosting many applications written in other frameworks (e.g. CodeIgniter) on this server and I never had such problems.

This problem appears only in the browser, e.g. when hitting a non-existing route: [example live s2 app hosted on this server](http://100nazorov.sk/non-existing-route/)

When I try to [curl the same uri](https://gist.github.com/3417637) I get proper output - a HTML formatted 404 error page.

When I was inspecting the http headers, the only difference I found between a regular page and an error page was this request header on a regular page:

```
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
```

While on the error page I read:

```
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate, sdch
```

I consulted this with the server admin, and he confirmed that no sdch configuration appears in his appache server. I also couldn't find any information that symfony2 would force this encoding on some servers depending on configuration - **as I don't have sdch appearing in this request header on other machines**.

This could and also doesn't have to be the reason, but right now I'm clueless..

Could there be a module loaded in this server that causes the problem maybe? How should I continue the investigation?

Comment: `curl --head http://100nazorov.sk/non-existing-route/` gives malformed  result. `Content-type` is not `text/html`.

Comment: @m2mdas I just tried the same and it returned `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to add browser agent string `curl --head http://100nazorov.sk/non-existing-route/ -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"`. `Content-type` is set to `text/vnd.wap.wml` here.